# Aborting a rebase doesn't work

Tags: git, git-rebase

I wanted to do an abort on an interactive rebase by doing `git rebase --abort`, but I am getting the error:

```
fatal: Could not parse object '7af12fc7e6ea2bb5231abe39c59cec9539f9536f'.
```

I've tried resetting the head and it didn't help. Any idea?

Comment: Did you try `git rebase --abort` (following the documentation: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html)?

Comment: +1 @Felix.  `git rebase -i abort` means you want to *start* an interactive rebase against a branch named `abort`.

Comment: yes, I did and it didn't work too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can abort a rebase using this method, too. Replace `<branch>` with whatever branch you happen to be rebasing:

```
cd .git
rm -rf rebase-merge
cd ..
git checkout <branch>
```

I.e, enter the `.git` directory, remove the rebase directory, go back to the repository (which is now in a detached HEAD state) and checkout the branch (which moves HEAD to the branch tip).